# Python Twitter scrapy used for extracting twitter following, followers count etc

Tags: python, scrapy

Im using scrapy to extract user info on twitter but im currently having issues extracting the following, followers count etc using python.

i can succesfully extract the id, screenname and avatar etc using..

```
user['ID'] = tweet['user_id']
user['name'] = item.xpath('.//@data-name').extract()[0]
user['screen_name'] = item.xpath('.//@data-screen-name').extract()[0]
user['avatar'] = item.xpath('.//div[@class="content"]/div[@class="stream-item-header"]/a/img/@src').extract()[0]
```

[twitter html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNXiR.png)

unfortunately im having issues extracting the attributes count from the 'following' html for the user as i do not know the correct xpath to extract the data or if its possible...

i can successfully extract the count using java script using the code below but having issues in python.

```
following   = $new.find('.ProfileNav-item--following .ProfileNav-value').first().text();
```

Any help and suggestions would be brilliant. 
thanks

picture of twitter without javascript
[twitter without javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVuuV.png)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether you have the element you are looking for, because the pages that your scraper downloads are without the elements rendered using javascript. You can check using `scrapy shell`([here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) is a link with info about scrapy shell). You can also find out the css selector using this [addon](http://selectorgadget.com/) or a similar one. 
Besides xpath you can use css selectors with scrapy
`item.css('<selector goes here>')`

Comment: So if it is in java script scrapy cannot extract the data? i have tried user['follower'] = item.css('.ProfileNav-item--following .ProfileNav-value').extract_first() but i still cannot seem to extract it

Comment: Yes, scrapy alone is not able to get content that was render using javascript. Try to [disable the javascript](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/BYOQskiuGU0/5PRO2P-1WWwJ) in your browser  and you will see how the page looks

Comment: There are add-ons for scrapy that can help you with javascript. Take a look at [this one](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash)

Comment: ive disabled javascript and can still see the html which i want to extract using scrapy (please see the new picture in the original comment) i still cannot seem to extract it. Ive tried........ user['follower'] = \
                        item.xpath('.//div[@class="stat"]/@statnum').extract()[0]

Comment: can you give me the twitter link or tell me how to get to the html from the screenshot?

Comment: yeah go to https://twitter.com/twitter for example, then hit f12 and then right click 'following' and select 'inspect element'. This will then bring up the html for that element. Thanks

Comment: Try this for testing `scrapy shell https://twitter.com/twitter` then `response.css('.ProfileNav-value::text').extract()[1]` you will get `145`. I guess this is the code you are looking for `user['follower'] = \ item.css('.ProfileNav-value::text').extract()[1] `